# Select2 implementation in html.slim in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, slim-lang

I am trying to implement a drop-down with the search using the select2 gem in rails. I installed the gem by adding it in the Gem file and running bundle install.

I kept the below command in application.js file

```
//= require select2
```

I kept the below command in .css file

```
/*
 *= require select2
 */
```

This is html for the html.slim

```
<select class="select required w-input text-field w-select positive" id="user_country_id" name="user[country_id]" required="required"><option value=""></option>
```

This is the html.slim code which needs to be implemented using select2

```
.w-row
            = form.association :country, as: :select, wrapper_html: {class: 'w-col w-col-6 w-sub-col'}, input_html: {class: 'w-select', required: true}, required: true
```

I tried adding the id in select2 js method given in documentation, but its not working for me.

```
javascript:
  | $(document).ready(function() { $("#user_country_id").select2(); });
```

I am a newbie here. Any help on how to implement select2 in html.slim using the association is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

put the call to javascript inside your slim file, at the bottom of the whole page, but remove the `Document.ready` function as follow:

```
javascript:
  $("#user_country_id").select2();
```

Since you are calling it after rendering the select, you don't need to call `Document.ready` again.

And if you will prefer to use coffeescript:

```
coffeeview:
  $('#user_country_id').select2
```

Comment: I still dint get the search with drop down, even after adding the js to the end of the file